# Picture does not show in iCarousel

Tags: ios, directory, icarousel

I am using the iCarousel to display my image, but strangely I did the codes right and nothing appears.  I am trying to display image from the directory folder.  In the directory folder I have few folders that have image saved in it.  Is there something missing?  I am almost there and I can't do it.  Also I have one warning at the last parenthesis of UIView saying control reaches end of non-void function.  Does this have something to do with this problem? I have put the return and it does not work. This is my code below.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSFileManager *fileManager  = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    //configure carousel1
    NSString *fPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Tops"];
    NSArray *directoryContent = [fileManager directoryContentsAtPath: fPath];
    imageArray1 = [directoryContent mutableCopy];

    //configure carousel2
    fPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Bottoms"];
    directoryContent = [fileManager directoryContentsAtPath:fPath];
    imageArray2 = [directoryContent mutableCopy];

    carousel1.type = iCarouselTypeLinear;
    carousel2.type = iCarouselTypeLinear;
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];

    //free up memory by releasing subviews
    self.carousel1 = nil;
    self.carousel2 = nil;
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark iCarousel methods

- (NSUInteger)numberOfItemsInCarousel:(iCarousel *)carousel
{
    //return the total number of items in the carousel
    if (carousel == carousel1)
    {
        return [imageArray1 count];
    }
    else
    {
        return [imageArray2 count];
    }
}
- (UIView *)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel viewForItemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index reusingView:(UIView *)view
{

    //create new view if no view is available for recycling
    if (view == nil)
    {
        view = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200.0f, 200.0f)];

        UIImage *image;
        if (carousel == carousel1)
        {
            image  = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[imageArray1 objectAtIndex:index]];
            ((UIImageView *)view).image = image;
        }
        else
        {
            image  = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[imageArray2 objectAtIndex:index]];
            ((UIImageView *)view).image = image;
        }
            return view;
    }}

- (CGFloat)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel valueForOption:(iCarouselOption)option withDefault:(CGFloat)value
{
    //customize carousel display
    switch (option)
    {
        case iCarouselOptionSpacing:
        {
            if (carousel == carousel2)
            {
                //add a bit of spacing between the item views
                return value * 1.05f;
            }
        }
        default:
        {
            return value;
        }
    }
}
```

feel free to ask if you want to see more code.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "iCarousel.h"


@interface iCarouselExampleViewController : UIViewController <iCarouselDataSource, iCarouselDelegate>{
    NSMutableArray *allImagesArray;
    NSMutableArray *imageArray1;
    NSMutableArray *imageArray2;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet iCarousel *carousel1;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet iCarousel *carousel2;

@end
```

Comment: Do you see any views / images? Have you checked the methods are called and the image arrays have images in them?

Comment: I don't see the views and images so its really strange. I only can see the background.  I have put 2 views in and declared it in my header.  Yes the array should have image in them.  I will also update my question putting the header file aswell.

Answer (score 0):

edit the code in - (UIView *)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel viewForItemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index reusingView:(UIView *)view  method as mentioned below --

```
- (UIView *)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel viewForItemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index reusingView:(UIView *)view {
if (view == nil)
{
    view = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200.0f, 200.0f)];

    UIImage *image;
    if (carousel == carousel1)
    {
        image  = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[imageArray1 objectAtIndex:index]];
        ((UIImageView *)view).image = image;
    }
    else
    {
        image  = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[imageArray2 objectAtIndex:index]];
        ((UIImageView *)view).image = image;
    }
        return view;
}
else {
    UIImage *image;
    if (carousel == carousel1)
    {
        image  = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[imageArray1 objectAtIndex:index]];
        ((UIImageView *)view).image = image;
    }
    else
    {
        image  = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[imageArray2 objectAtIndex:index]];
        ((UIImageView *)view).image = image;
    }
}


return view;
}
```

may be the problem is with your code where if (view != nil) then your code doesn't have implementation of setting image for view in icarousel.

Comment: This won't work since getting errors from it sayin expected method body
expected':'
expected identifier or (
expected identifier or (
extraneous closing brace ("}")

Comment: yeah it will throw errors bcoz you need to add below mentioned line before this code -                                                            - (UIView *)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel viewForItemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index reusingView:(UIView *)view
{

Comment: now i have edited the answer so that you can copy and paste it. it will work. but don't forget to accept the answer and marking it up.